# How to make background transparent?

Tags: android, layout

I am creating a background for a Textview object like this in XML:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_enabled="true">
      <shape android:padding="50dp"
          android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/sendDarkColor"    android:endColor="@color/sendDarkColor" android:angle="90"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

sendDarkColor is just black. But I want this black to be transparent. Similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndovz.png

This xml is later is set to a Textview as mentioned. I want it be a little transparent. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just change sendDarkColor to have transparency. Ex. #33000000

Comment: Thank you very much.. If I wanna make it darker should I increase the 33 part to like 88 or 99?

Answer (score 0):

The color structure is like this **AARRGGBB** where AA is the alpha color in hexadecimal notation. For example, value for 50% transparency is **#7FFFFFFF**

Comment: FFFFFFF is white though? so how can I have black? sorry don't quite understand

Comment: #7F000000 would be what you want for 50% transparency

Comment: Yes you can have black as @dymmeh said, **FFFFFF** is just an example based on the code that you posted. The first two digits specify the transparency, 7F (127 in decimal) is the 50% because FF (255 in decimal)is the 100% of transparency, the rest of the numbers are the color. Example _#7FFFFFFF_ for black or _#7FFF0000_ for red with the transparency at 50%.

Comment: so if I want 20% transparency, it would be 51 decimal. How should I convert this to a 7F(hex??) value? Is it hex?

Comment: 51 is 33 in hex, the color would be _#33FFFFFF_

Comment: Use [this chart](http://www.webelfin.com/webelfindesign/colorconvert.html) to convert from decimal to hex

Answer (score 0):

To have black transparent color use:

```
android:background="#50000000"
```

or just use the color `"#50000000"` wherever you place a BG. The first two numbers after `"#"`, sets the opacity/transparency of the color. Hope this helps. Write if you don't understand something.

Comment: Huh? Valid alphas are 00 to FF in hex.. so 0 to 255 in decimal. half of 255 is 127. 127 in hex is 7F. So, 50% transparency should be 7F hex. Not 50

Comment: oh. Thanks. I thought it was from 00 to 99. Well my bad. Thanks. Its working though.